# Optimizing R code for vectorized operations

Tags: r, performance, optimization, data.table, runtime

Here is a piece of R code that works fine at the moment :

`x` being a `"numeric"`, `unit` a `"character"` and `digits` a `"numeric"`

```
process <- function(x, unit, digits) { 
  if (unit == "$") {
    x <- comprss(x)
    } else {
      x <- reformat(x,digits)
      }
  } 

x <- mapply(process, x, unit, digits)
```

I'm using `mapply` because I want to apply the functions to a vector `x`. `x` being a column of a `data.table`, so are `unit` and `digits`, they are all of the same length.

I could vectorize the functions `comprss` and `reformat` and apply them with a conditional boolean vector on x but here is my problem :

The functions `comprss` and `reformat` both take an integer as argument and return a character. Therefore, with the vectorized functions, if I apply the first one, the class of x changes from `"numeric"` to `"character"` and the second one cannot be applied anymore, that's why I'm using `mapply` instead of vectorized functions.

But this method doesn't not take advantage of vectorized operations and is pretty slow. Is there something better you can think about ? And using `data.table` syntax ?

Comment: Could you provide reproducible input data. Also, what is the question? Furthermore, where does comprss() and reformat() come from?

Comment: I'm inferring your need for `data.table`-semantics, even though your question doesn't show using the package at all. If you're really doing something like `DT[, x := mapply(process, x, unit, digits), by=grp]`, then I suggest you make a different column first and then reassign, ala `DT[, x2 := mapply(process, x, unit, digits), by=grp][, x := x2][, x2 := NULL]` (or some other way to swap things around).

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr which is considerably faster than your approach (although it's hard to guess what your functions exactly do)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
library(rbenchmark)

comprss <- function(x) {
  paste(x)
}

reformat <- function(x, digits){
  format(x,nsmall = digits)
}

process <- function(x, unit, digits) { 
  if (unit == "$") {
    x <- comprss(x)
  } else {
    x <- reformat(x,digits)
  }
} 

x <- runif(100000,1,20000)
unit <- stri_rand_strings(100000,1,"[$€]")
digits <- floor(runif(100000,1,10))
df <- data.frame(x,
                 unit,
                 digits)

benchmark("dplyr" = {
  y <- df %>% mutate(y = if_else(unit == "$", comprss(x), reformat(x, digits))) %>% pull(y)
},
"question" = {
  y <- mapply(process, x, unit, digits)
},
replications = 5)
```

```
      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1    dplyr            5    0.86    1.000      0.83     0.00         NA        NA
2 question            5    5.94    6.907      5.67     0.08         NA        NA
```

This is your process-function as a dplyr `if_else`:

```
y <- df %>% mutate(y = if_else(unit == "$", comprss(x), reformat(x, digits))) %>% pull(y)
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's indeed much better ! And sorry for not sharing the functions...

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), then yes, changing the class of a column by-group is not going to work well:

```r
library(data.table)
MT <- as.data.table(head(mtcars))
MT[, disp := paste("qq", disp), by = cyl]
# Warning in `[.data.table`(MT, , `:=`(disp, paste("qq", disp)), by = cyl) :
#   Coercing 'character' RHS to 'double' to match the type of the target column (column 0 named '').
# Warning in `[.data.table`(MT, , `:=`(disp, paste("qq", disp)), by = cyl) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
# Warning in `[.data.table`(MT, , `:=`(disp, paste("qq", disp)), by = cyl) :
#   Coercing 'character' RHS to 'double' to match the type of the target column (column 0 named '').
# Warning in `[.data.table`(MT, , `:=`(disp, paste("qq", disp)), by = cyl) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
# Warning in `[.data.table`(MT, , `:=`(disp, paste("qq", disp)), by = cyl) :
#   Coercing 'character' RHS to 'double' to match the type of the target column (column 0 named '').
# Warning in `[.data.table`(MT, , `:=`(disp, paste("qq", disp)), by = cyl) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
```

But you can do it by assigning to a new or already-string (throwaway) column and then reassign:

```r
MT[, disp2 := paste("qq", disp), by = cyl][, disp := disp2][, disp2 := NULL][]
#      mpg   cyl   disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#    <num> <num> <char> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:  21.0     6 qq 160   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1     4     4
# 2:  21.0     6 qq 160   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1     4     4
# 3:  22.8     4 qq 108    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
# 4:  21.4     6 qq 258   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
# 5:  18.7     8 qq 360   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
# 6:  18.1     6 qq 225   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
```

In your case, I think it would be

```r
DT[, x2 := mapply(process, x, unit, digits), by = yourgroup
  ][, x := x2][, x2 := NULL]
```